# Scaling Times Table Exercises

Tags: floating-point, type

I would like to create exercise worksheets based on random numbers that scale multiplication and division facts up and down.

For example, once a student learns that: **5*3=15**, it is time to scale that knowledge up to **5*3000=15000** and down to **0.5*0.3=0.15**.

How do I do this?

Here is some code I've created to scale multiplication facts *up*. But it seems to break whenever scaled by a factor of 1000 or more. Why?

Also, to scale multiplication facts down, integers will not apply. What do I do then?

Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\OneExercise}
 {\pgfmathrandominteger{\FactorA}{1}{10}
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{PowerOfTen}{{1}{10}{100}{1000}}
  \pgfmathrandomitem{\PowerOfTen}{PowerOfTen}
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\FactorBInteger}{1}{10}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\FactorB}{int(\FactorBInteger*\PowerOfTen)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Product}{int(\FactorA*\FactorB)}

  \(\FactorA\times\FactorB = \Product\)
   }

\begin{document}

\section*{Scaled Up Times Tables}

\foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,5}
    {\OneExercise }

\end{document}
```

Comment: On a somewhat related note, how do I show latex or mathjax style-formatting of equations inside the body of these posts?

Comment: MathJax is not enabled here, so you can't, unless you want to upload screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

`pgf` sometimes struggles with large numbers, thought I don't know why it failed here. `xfp` handles such things a bit better, so you could use that instead.

For scaling up or down, draw a random integer from -3 to 3, and scale by 10 to the power of that integer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf, xfp}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\OneExercise}
 {\pgfmathrandominteger{\FactorA}{1}{10}
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\TenPower}{-3}{3}
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\FactorBInteger}{1}{10}
  \def\FactorB{\fpeval{\FactorBInteger*10^{\TenPower}}}
  \def\Product{\fpeval{\FactorA*\FactorB}}

  \(\FactorA\times\FactorB = \Product\)
   }

\begin{document}

\section*{Scaled Up Times Tables}

\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    {\OneExercise }

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple solution. the `xfp` ctan website, though, barely says anything about it and doesn't really describe what `\fpeval` does. How is it different from what pgf` does?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything `\fpeval` is "floating point evaluation", and `\fpeval{1+1}` returns `2` (as described in the manual). So that's one difference in use, `pgf` doesn't have any macros that directly returns the result of the calculation. At a more fundamental level, the calculations are implemented in a different way, meaning that `xfp` is not as limited. Exactly how the implementations differ I cannot say though, because I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `expl3` at the outset?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp,pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\doseveral}{m+m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\declarefpvar}{mo}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_wcla_math_var_#1_fp }
  \IfValueT { #2 } { \fp_set:cn { l_wcla_math_var_#1_fp } { #2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_set:cn { l_wcla_math_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\declarefpvector}{mo}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_wcla_math_vector_#1_seq }
  \IfValueT { #2 } { \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_wcla_math_vector_#1_seq } { #2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvector}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_wcla_math_vector_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomitem}{m}
 {
  \seq_rand_item:c { l_wcla_math_vector_#1_seq }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_wcla_math_var_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\OneExercise}{%
  \declarefpvar{FactorA}[randint(1,10)]%
  \declarefpvector{PowerOfTen}[0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]%
  \declarefpvar{FactorB}[randint(1,10)*\randomitem{PowerOfTen}]%
  \declarefpvar{Product}[\usefpvar{FactorA}*\usefpvar{FactorB}]%
  \(\usefpvar{FactorA}\times\fpeval{\usefpvar{FactorB}} = \usefpvar{Product}\)
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Scaled Up Times Tables}

These are twelve exercises

\doseveral{12}{\OneExercise\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks more complex than the `xfp` solution posted by Torbjorn. Is there an advantage to this apparent complexity?

Comment: The complex part is reimplementing the operations you need; I find the user syntax much more straightforward.